# Software/code to extract a solenoidal (a.k.a. divergence-free) field from a 2D vector field numerically

Tags: numerical-analysis, fluid-dynamics, software, vector

Can somebody point me to software/code to extract a solenoidal (a.k.a. divergence-free) field from a 2D vector field numerically?

There are a plethora of papers and documents describing how to do this, but for some reason none of the authors (or anybody else for that matter) puts a simple piece of source code online implementing that functionality. All I found are rather huge packages or very cryptic pieces of code.

Update. More concretely for my situation:
I have two 2D arrays of size 64x64 with double-precision floating point numbers. These two arrays represent the x- and y-velocities of a fluid flow. Periodic boundaries are employed. I would like to extract the solenoidal part of the velocities into two new 2D arrays.

Comment: Do you want to do this analytically or do you have your field defined over a mesh? How is it done? Maybe if you write more details about it, somebody can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I thought the tags 'numerical-analysis' and 'numerics' would be sufficient for that. Updated question

Comment: I believe the numerical vs. analytical question was just a specific example of where details are missing. Here is another. Is this over a bounded domain in 2D? If so, is it rectangular?

Comment: Maybe the solenoidal part comes as the solution of certain PDEs? You can check what equations it satisfies. Then solve the PDEs for it.

Comment: Posting a question on stackexchange is walking a very thin line. I have seen questions closed because they were too generic, yet also because they were too specific. Hopefully the question is now in order.

Comment: Your question was not specific enough. People made comments trying to help other people understand what you want. Since contributions here are done in people's free time, they prefer to invest that time in well written questions.

Comment: What programming language do you prefer? Do you need to perform this task once? Or actively as a part of some other code? I.e. Is performance important? You'll likely have to solve a poison equation for a scalar field, whose source term is the divergence of your velocity field. Then just subtract the gradient of the scalar field from your original field. What shape are the control volumes? Rectangles? What order of accuracy do you need for the spatial discretization? These are some examples of questions that people need to know to provide you with a good answer..

Comment: That said, I agree that many packages are large and cryptic. There are small codes out there, though. For example, I wrote a short (less than 200 lines) code to solve the 2D incompressible Navier Stokes, which performs the very task you're asking about. The code is here: https://github.com/charliekawczynski/short_LDC_fortran_2D. It's written in Fortran, however, and it's based on rectangular elements with 2nd order spatial accuracy and 1st order temporal accuracy.

Comment: @Charlie: apologies for the delay. Thanks for the pointers. As for your questions:
C/C++ preferred. 
I only have to do it once (so performance is not an issue). 
Rectangular control shapes. Exact accuracy is not very important, it's just for testing an idea. 
As for solving Poisson equation, agree, but is there somewhere a small and easy to use piece of C/C++ code that does that?

Comment: @Bart, I suggest you update your question and include these, and as many specific details, as you can. I realized that I forgot to ask additional questions: are the velocity fields staggered? Or collocated? Is the mesh uniform or non-uniform? Do you understand the procedure required to perform the task you're asking about? The field you seek is $u^{div-free} = u^{initial} - \nabla \phi, \nabla^2 \phi = \nabla \bullet u^{initial}$. What are the BCs for $\phi$? Until you include all of this information, you may wait a long time for someone to, if ever, answer your question.

Comment: I'm basically reiterating @nicoguaro's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I found a C/C++ function called project() in the article
'Real-Time Fluid Dynamics for Games' by Jos Stam
http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/stam/reality/Research/pdf/GDC03.pdf
I had to do a little bit of editing, such as increasing iteration variable `k` (dependent on how divergent your input field is) and employing periodic boundaries. After that it worked for me and solved my problem. The article also contains a fairly intuitive description of what the function outputs without going into the details of how it does this.

I also found the reasonably small Python software package windspharm can extract a solenoidal field
http://ajdawson.github.io/windspharm/api/windspharm.cdms.html#windspharm.cdms.VectorWind.nondivergentcomponent
I did not test this one though.